# Is there a security risk/vulnerability in having a page on your site that can effectively redirect to any other page on the site?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, security

Let's say I have this controller action

```
    public IActionResult LandingPage(string path)
    {
        ViewBag.path = path;
        return View();
    }
```

and in that view is just javascript that will take that path variable out of the viewbag and redirect to whatever's in it like below

```
<script>         
    var path= '@ViewBag.path';
    window.location.replace('../' + path);
</script>
```

essentially allowing for the client to reach any path on the site.  Does this pose any security risks in allowing a savvy user to put whatever they want in the redirect path?

Comment: Yes. Imagine you have `/users/deleteAccount` which immediately deletes the user's account. Or you have `/posts/add` which adds a post to the site.

Comment: See [Unvalidated forwards and redirects](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet.html)

Comment: Ideally you should not have any `GET` actions with side-effects. Also, why return a view with javascript when you can just `Redirect(...)`?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar couldn't someone just put those paths into the address bar themselves for the same effect?  As long as they have authorization, which they would need either way.

Comment: you need to consider construction of links for phishing attacks.... John Wu's link there spells it all out.